# How to create a custom OpenFiledialog Property for a UserControl

Tags: wpf, properties, wpf-controls, dependency-properties

When I right click a `UserControl` and select **Properties**, I want to create a custom property inside the `UserControl` properties that loads a file from an `OpenFileDialog`, like the **ColumnDefinitions**, but that browses inside my machine:

[image]

How can I achieve that? I've been searching but I'm a bit lost on where to start from.

NOTE: The image indicates that the property I want to create is one of the properties of the `UserControl` that appear when you **Right click->Properties** the `UserControl`.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to define a dependency property in your user control?  Or an attached property?  Also, when do you want the file loaded?  As soon as the property value changes?

Comment: An attached one, and I want the file to be loaded when I run the project ( so I guess this is the basic one...).

Comment: Why don't you open a file dialog in the loaded event of the user control ?

Comment: Because maybe the user doesn't need to loada file. Is an option of my UserControl. That's why I need it to be a Property of the UserControl.

Comment: What's the picture for? It seems to have no connection to this question.

Comment: Actually I'm telling what kind of property I want to create. I want to create a custom property on the properties menu of my UserControl. That's why.

Comment: @Sonhja, I might be starting to get it.  Do you want to write a user control that contains a file selector/browser from which the end user can select a file, and you want this dialog to be shown when the application loads?

Comment: No, I want this selecter to be an option of the right click properties of the UserControl (as the ones you can see on the image).I want to add an extra property to the UserControl, to be able to do some stuff on design time. 
I'm providing a custom UserContorl, so it has it's own properties. But I can't get how to do a customized browser on the properties.

Answer (score 1):

I declared a property for searching execuble files in an OpenFileDialog in a WinForm project. The code is in VB .NET.

First create a Class like this:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Design
Imports System.Windows.Forms.Design
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class ExecutableEditor : Inherits UITypeEditor

    Public Overrides Function GetEditStyle(context As System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext) As System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditorEditStyle
        Return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function EditValue(context As System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext, provider As System.IServiceProvider, value As Object) As Object
        If context Is Nothing And context.Instance Is Nothing And provider Is Nothing Then
            Return value
        End If

        Dim editor_service As IWindowsFormsEditorService = _
            CType(provider.GetService(GetType(IWindowsFormsEditorService)),  _
                IWindowsFormsEditorService)

        If editor_service Is Nothing Then Return value

        Dim ofdEjecutable As New OpenFileDialog
        ofdEjecutable.Title = "Select an executable file"
        ofdEjecutable.FileName = Nothing
        ofdEjecutable.Filter = "executable file|*.exe"

        If ofdEjecutable.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            Return ofdEjecutable.FileName
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function

End Class
```

Then in the code of the UserControl declare a property like this:

```
Private _executable As String
<Category("Injection")> _
<EditorAttribute(GetType(ExecutableEditor), GetType(UITypeEditor))> _
Public Property Executable As String
    Get
        Return _executable
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _executable = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

What I got from your question is that you want a Browsable Property for you user control. Going by this, for simple .net property add:

```
    private string myString;
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Other")]
    public string MyProperty { get { return myString; } set { myString = value; } }
```

and in setter of the property load the file after validation.

If you want it to be dependancy property do the same but move the code of loading the file in the propertychange handler.

Comment: More or less. I need it to have a button on the right that opens an OpenFileDialog. Any idea?